# Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: c#

Here is the code:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery] string sort,  [FromQuery] string sortColumn, [FromQuery] int perPage = 10, [FromQuery] int page = 0)
{
    string searchString = string.Empty;

    var ncquery =  _context.NonConformities .AsQueryable();

    var ncfilter = Helper.OrderBy(ncquery, sortColumn, sort == "asc")
        .Skip(perPage * (page - 1))
        .Take(perPage);

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        ncfilter = ncfilter.Where(nc => nc.Title.Contains(searchString));
    }
    var data = await (from nc in _context.NonConformities
                        join mdt in _context.MasterData on nc.NcTypes equals mdt.Id
                        join mdo in _context.MasterData on nc.Originator equals mdo.Id
                        join mdd in _context.MasterData on nc.Department equals mdd.Id
                        join mdc in _context.MasterData on nc.Category equals mdc.Id
                        join mds in _context.MasterData on nc.Status equals mds.Id

                        select new
                        {
                            Id = nc.Id,
                            Title = nc.Title,
                            Originator = mdo.Items,
                            Department = mdd.Items,
                            Date = nc.Date,
                            NcTypes = mdt.Items,
                            Category = mdc.Items,
                            Status = mds.Items,
                            Description = nc.Description,
                            Evidence = nc.Evidence,
                            ReviewRecommendation = nc.ReviewRecommendation,
                            }).ToListAsync();

    //await ncfilter.ToListAsync();

    var totalItems = await _context.NonConformities.CountAsync();

    int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(totalItems / (double)perPage);

    var model = new PaginatedItems<NonConformity>(page, perPage, totalPages, data );

    return Ok(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is in the line

```
var model = new PaginatedItems<NonConformity>(page, perPage, totalPages, data );
```

You need to have a list of `NonConformity` instead of a list of anonymous type:

```
select new
{
   Id = nc.Id,
   ...
})
.ToListAsync() // Fetch the records from the database
.Select( x => new NonConformity(...)); // Transform them into NonConformity objects
```

Comment: Or maybe extend the anonymous type with a member holding the instance of NonConformity to not have nonconformity -> anonymous-> nonconformity